# Amazon RDS CPU Usage keep increasing without any long running process in Show Processlist

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds

We are using Amazon RDS(db.m2.2xlarge), CPU usage is suddenly increasing gradually even after  we reboot the DB Server. This is happening just past 2 days and we didn't give any new build recently.

I tried to debug using "SHOW PROCESSLIST" and identified long running process. I killed it but still CPU % is not reduced. Actually we just have 10 process at a time

Comment: Having monitoring (graphs are the most visual way to do that) of some of the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS variables can be very helpful for debugging (com_, Handler_, threads varaibles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should keep an eye on things like your buffer sizes, table cache, query cache and innodb_buffer_pool_size, key_buffer_size as all of these memory allocations can have an affect on query performance which can cause MySQL to eat up CPU.
- Enable slow query log and see if there are queries getting logged there.
- Observe "mysqladmin status" output for sometime certain values like "Questions, Slow queries, Open tables, Queries per second avg" should help.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh, There was some query executed frequently to keep CPU busy.